# Remove XElement from XDocument Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an `XDocument` and i want to remove `XElement` from this.

I try this code :-

```
XDocument XDoc = XDocument.Parse(XMLFile);

    var PricedItineraryRemove = XDoc.Descendants("PricedItinerary");

    foreach (XElement xle in PricedItineraryRemove)
    {
         if (xle.Attribute("SequenceNumber").Value != SequenceNumber.ToString())
         {
               xEle.Remove(); //this line giving error second time.
         }
    }
```

`xEle.Remove()` working correctly first time but second time giving `System.InvalidOperationException` Exception.

Comment: The code you've given wouldn't even compile - you haven't declared `xEle`. You should also give the *full* exception details - I suspect there's a helpful message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to use this code to remove nodes with specific attribute:

```
string sequenceNumberStr = SequenceNumber.ToString();

XDoc.Descendants("PricedItinerary")
    .Where(node => (string)node.Attribute("SequenceNumber") != sequenceNumberStr)
    .Remove();
```

Comment: +1 Btw I think `(string)node.Attribute("SequenceNumber")` will be more safe

Answer (score 3):

The `PricedItineraryRemove` is an `IEnumerable<XElement>` which is lazily evaluated when you start `foreach`ing. Now when you start removing parts of the DOM during this iteration, this iterator gets confused and dies.
Simple solution: Add a .ToList() or .ToArray() so that the list is pre-evaluated and no-one can get confused anymore:

```
foreach (XElement xle in PricedItineraryRemove.ToList())
```

Comment: Good to see that you provided the reason why it does not work.